# How to replace block text with help blockinfile?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

i need replace block text in file. It:

```
  passwd:         compat
  group:          compat
  shadow:         compat
```

by:

```
  passwd:         compat ldap
  group:          compat ldap
  shadow:         compat ldap
```

I don't understand how to do it. I read man blockinfile, but how replaced text don't know:

```
- name: Update /etc/nsswitch.conf
  blockinfile:
    dest: /etc/nsswitch.conf
    marker: ""
    block: |
      passwd:         compat
      group:          compat
      shadow:         compat
```

Pls need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use lineinfile:

```
      - name: Update /etc/nsswitch.conf
        lineinfile: dest=/etc/nsswitch.conf regexp="{{ item.regexp }}" line="{{ item.line }}"
        with_items:
           - { regexp: '^passwd:.*compat', line: 'passwd: compat ldap' }
           - { regexp: '^group:.*compat', line: 'group: compat ldap' }
           - { regexp: '^shadow:.*compat', line: 'shadow: compat ldap' }
```

Comment: This fails if the lines needs to be in a specific order, e.g. to replace a function with another...